# InvalidCastException with custom generic TypeConverter for use within MCV environment, need fix

Tags: c#, generics, casting, typeconverter

I need a TypeConverter that, idealy, translates a String to a type safe enum class (CountryIso) without having to write a converter for every type safe enum I'm about to make.

While I managed to get the following to work:

```
CountryIso cI = (CountryIso) "1";
```

**I just can't get it to work with generics! The following sample doesn't work, but why?**

```
TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(new ExplicitCastDescriptionProvider<CountryIso>(), typeof(CountryIso));
var descriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(CountryIso));
var result = descriptor.ConvertFrom("1");
```

I currently have a generic TypeConverter implementation:

```
public class ExplicitCastConverter<T>: TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        // Always true: the type determines if a cast is available or not
        return true;
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        String dummy = (String) value;
        //CountryIso tst = (CountryIso) value; // Allowed, no problem casting
        //CountryIso tst = (CountryIso) dummy; // Allowed, no problem casting
        //var dum_001 = (T) ((String) value); // Does not compile
        //var dumdum = (T) value; // Invalid case exception
        //var hoot = (T) Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof (T)); // Invalid cast exception
        return null;
    }
}
```

The Provider is as follows:

```
//thanks: http://groups.google.com/group/wpf-disciples/browse_thread/thread/9f7bb40b7413fcd
public class ExplicitCastDescriptionProvider<T> : TypeDescriptionProvider //where T:TypeSafeEnum
{
    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, object instance)
    {
        return new ImplicitCastDescription<T>();
    }
}

public class ImplicitCastDescription<T>: CustomTypeDescriptor //where T:TypeSafeEnum
{
    public override TypeConverter GetConverter()
    {
        return new ExplicitCastConverter<T>();
    }
}
```

I have a type safe enum implementation CountryIso (thanks StackOverflow!):

```
public sealed class CountryIso: TypeSafeEnum
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<int, CountryIso> InstanceDict = new Dictionary<int, CountryIso>();

    public static readonly CountryIso NL = new CountryIso(1, "NL", "Netherlands");
    public static readonly CountryIso BE = new CountryIso(2, "BE", "Belgium");

    private CountryIso(int value, String name, String description): base(value,name,description)
    {
        InstanceDict.Add(value, this);
    }

    public static Dictionary<int, CountryIso> Instances
    {
        get { return new Dictionary<int, CountryIso>(InstanceDict); }
    }

    public static explicit operator CountryIso(String i)
    {
        int index;
        return Int32.TryParse(i,out index) ? InstanceDict[index] : null;
    }
}
```

Which inherits from TypeSafeEnum:

```
public class TypeSafeEnum
{
    protected TypeSafeEnum(int value, String name, String description)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
        Description = description;
    }

    public int Value{ get; private set; }
    public String Name { get; private set; }
    public String Description { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**One option: use reflection**

The problem lies with the static nature of the CountryIso members and (*mostly*) the casting operators. This prevents any blueprint definition enabling a generic typeconverter to know it can cast the CountryIso type safe enum. Also, you cannot cast 'down': a TypeSafeEnum can never become a CountryIso. Which is logical, but doesn't help.

**[ Using reflection ]**

1. Introduced a generic interface defining a casting method:

   ```
   public interface ICast<out T>
   {
       T Cast(String obj);
   }
   ```
2. Apply interface to CountryIso

   ```
   public sealed class CountryIso: TypeSafeEnum , ICast<CountryIso>
   ```
3. Add interface as contstraint to the converter class

   ```
   public class ExplicitCastConverter<T>: TypeConverter where T: ICast<T>
   ```
4. Add a (non-static) cast method to my CountryIso:

   ```
   public new CountryIso Cast(String obj)
   {
       int index;
       return Int32.TryParse(obj, out index) ? InstanceDict[index] : null;
   }
   ```
5. Added a default static member to my type-safe-enum:

   ```
   private static readonly CountryIso DefaultTypeSafeEnum = new CountryIso(
       -1,
       null,
       null
   );
   ```
6. Implement the ConvertFrom(..) in the Converter class:

   ```
   T defaultMember = (T)typeof(T).GetField(
       "DefaultTypeSafeEnum",
       BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static
   ).GetValue(null);

   return defaultMember.Cast((String) value);
   ```

**[ Type safe enum security ]**

It's *still* possible to create & insert new instances of CountryIso via reflection (especially when using the InstanceDict for easy instance access!) Some sample code:

```
ConstructorInfo ci = typeof (T).GetConstructor(
    BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance,
    null,
    CallingConventions.Standard,
    new [] {typeof (int), typeof (String), typeof (String)},
    new ParameterModifier[0]
);

CountryIso countryIso = (CountryIso) ci.Invoke(new object[]{30, "ZB", "Zanzibar"});
```

I now consider the usage of the private InstanceDict member a **security hole** (not a big one, since I'm not programming an API for the outside world, but still...)